# Renewing SSL certificate Service Fabric endpoint

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

How can I renew certificate on a service fabric https endpoint after it expires?

I use port sharing for multi-domain support (`WebListener`) and `netsh` to bind cert to `ip:port` (I can't use manifest file to bind domain name, is not supported now).

But if I don't want to upload new package version (only for run `SetupEntryPoint`) is there a way to send a `netsh` command to VM Scale Sets?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the same command, like netsh, on all the VMs in a scale set, a good way to do this is to use a custom script extension. You can add a custom script extension using the PowerShell cmdlet Add-AzureRmVmssExtension.